# How to retain Textbox values after a Postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have few Textbox, FileUpload and button controls within the same page. I had tried enabling the EnableViewState to True but it is still not working. The Textbox will lose its value when clicking the button to upload attachments. May I know what's wrong here, should I use ViewState to retain the values of the textboxes?

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6" >
            <asp:Label ID="lblConfiguration" runat="server" Text="Configuration*"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtConfiguration" runat="server" type="text" class="form-control" EnableViewState="true"  ViewStateMode="Enabled" ></asp:TextBox>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <asp:FileUpload ID="fuUpload" runat="server" CssClass="nv-file-select uploader" multiple="true" /> 
            <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" CssClass="btn btn-secondary" />  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you enable viewstate on page level also?

Comment: I can't find such parameter in the Page and master page. It is still not working even I enable it at page level and master page.

Comment: the parameter is shown in Aristos answer. does the textbox maintain its value, if you strip down your page to the minimum, e.g. only textbox and button?

Comment: I haven't done that. I will resort to bind the values of the controls into ViewState as the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Possible reasons

1) You have disable the Viewstate on full page - Check on top of aspx page if its enable or not

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="FileName.ascx.cs" EnableViewState="true" %>
```

2) At some point on code behind you change the value on post back - so check to not change it by adding this check

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    TextBox.Text = "";
}
```

3) For some reason after your post back you do redirect on same page.

4) For some reason you do not make post back, but reload

Comment: I had done step 1) before posting this question. It didn't work. 2) 3) 4) not

Comment: But  AutoEventWireup="true" is in the master page. Not sure what does this do.

Comment: I have found out the cause of problem. I was rebinding the controls with empty value from DB as I'm sharing edit and new entry with one page. EnableViewState works when I remark out the controls rebinding. Thanks.